# How to validate a config entity form?

Tags: forms

I have a config entity with a form which extends `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm`, which has a public `form()` and a public `save()` methods. They both work fine and dandy. I want to validate some information before saving the form. As far as I can tell there's a `validateForm()` method already built in via the class it extends.

I can't seem to find much information on how to do that. I've tried the obvious, simply setting a `return false` in the `validateForm` method but it doesn't seem to be called at all.

I don't have much experience with Drupal in general so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

If anybody could point me in the right direction here, I'd be grateful.

I'd also like to keep the field values in case of an error. I can only assume that that happens by default, but then again I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `validateForm` method in your own form class. Just declare a method like so:

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Your custom validation code.
}
```

Since the [Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBase.php/class/FormBase/8.3.x) (parent of [Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityForm.php/class/EntityForm/8.3.x)) class has no validation, just a blank method, there is no need to call the parent method from your own class.

Comment: I did overwrite the parent method in my own classs, but it doesn't seem to be called at all. As I said, I assume I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It should call the `validateForm()`, I just checked in one of my own entity forms. What happens if you place an `exit()` in the `validateForm()` method? 

P.S. Errors can be added by calling the `setErrorByName()` or `setError()` methods on the `$form_state` not by returning `FALSE`.

Comment: You were correct. I keep forgetting to clear the cache. It works properly now. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!